# convert time in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing an `xml` file in `python` and I need to convert the following date and time format to something human-friendly:

```
  <due_date>735444</due_date>
  <due_time>55800</due_time>
```

The format of date seems to be number of days since year 0, and time is the number of seconds since midnight.
How could I convert it into some standard format, such as `2014-07-30 15:30:00` ?

Comment: First step is to find out a "formula" of what those numbers mean..

Comment: @kasparg: uhm, no. This is not a timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.fromordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromordinal) plus a `timedelta()` for the seconds after midnight:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(due_date) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=due_time)
```

Your `due_date` is relative to the year 1 instead, as your values fit to produce your expected date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> due_date = 735444
>>> due_time = 55800
>>> datetime.datetime.fromordinal(due_date) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=due_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 30, 15, 30)
```